# $a*b=a \iff a=0$ or $b=1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, discrete-mathematics, solution-verification, integers

> $a$ and $b$ are integers. $$a*b=a \iff a=0 \ \text{or} \ b=1$$

First, i tried using the right side to prove the left, so
$$b=1 \Longrightarrow a*1=a \Longrightarrow a=a$$
$$ a=0 \Longrightarrow 0*b=0$$ whereas b can have any value.

The way around would be:

Supose b is invertible, then
$$ab=a \Longrightarrow a * (b*b^{-1})= a*b^{-1}$$
$$ \Longrightarrow a*1=a*b^{-1} \Longrightarrow a=ab^{-1}  $$
Therefore
$$ab=a=ab^{-1}$$
Supose $a≠0$ then $b = b^{-1}$ iff $b=1$ or $b=-1$

If $a=0$ b can be any integer.

Any other ideas? Is that correct?

Comment: That's obviously not correct, since $b=-1$ cannot happen. Plus the reasoning is somewhat convoluted. The proper solution is turning the equation into $a(b-1)=0$ and the conclusion follows since integers don't have zero divisors.

Comment: Alternative : Basic result of Field Theory applied to the field of real numbers: for any real numbers $~r,s~$ you have that $~r \times s = 0 \implies [r = 0 ~~\text{or} ~~s = 0].$

Comment: I understand why b can’t be -1, but how do i get to this equation?

Comment: For a `solution-verification` question to be on topic you must specify *precisely* which step in the proof you question, and *why so*. This site is not meant to be used as a proof checking machine.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because is a generic proof checking question lacking the necessary context, i.e. which step is in doubt and why so.

Answer (score 5):

You should base your proof on:

$ab = a \iff$
$ab - a = 0 \iff$
$a \cdot (b-1) = 0$

The multiplication of two integers is zero is (at least) one of the integers is zero.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $ab = a$. We go by cases.

Case: $a = 0$. Done.

Case: $a \neq 0$. By the division theorem, there exist unique integers $q, r$ such that $0 \leq r < |a|$ and $qa + r = a$. Note that $1a + 0 = a$. Since $q$ is unique, $q = 1$. We know that $ba + 0 = a$. Since $q$ is unique, $q = b$. Since $q = 1$ and $q = b$, $b = 1$.

Now, suppose $a = 0 \lor b = 1$. We go by cases.

Case: $a = 0$. $ab = 0b = 0 = a$.

Case: $a \neq 0$. Since $a = 0 \lor b = 1$, $b = 1$. $ab = a1 = a$.

Answer (score 0):

Your firts part is correct (when you supposed $a=1$ or $b=0$). But I think that the second implication is not totally correct.

I mean, I don't know how "abstract" is your problem. If you are working with integers in a intuitive level then I could say that your solution is fine. But in a context of abstract algebra, the integers are a ring (a conmutative ring with unity if you want a more detailed name) and you can't suppose that a number $b$ is invertible. For example, the number $2$ doesn't have a number $x \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $2x = 2*x = 1$.

I let this short pdf that I found on a random website with the definitions we need:
[PDF with definitions of groups and rings](http://www2.gcc.edu/dept/math/faculty/BancroftED/teaching/handouts/group_ring_definitions.pdf)

If you know the axioms of groups and rings you can avoid the pdf.

Let $(\mathbb{Z}, + , \cdot)$ be a ring, where $+$ and $\cdot$ are usual sum and product respectively. Denote $a\cdot b = ab$ and $a + (-b) = a - b$ for any integers $a$ and $b$.

**First result:**

Let $a$ be any integer. Then $a0 = 0$.

*Proof:*
$a 0 = a ( a - a) = aa - aa = 0$.

Due to distribute law and definition of inverse element of $+$ operation.

**Second result:**

Let $a$ and $b$ be any integers. If $ab = 0$ the $a= 0$ or $b=0$.

*Proof:*

\begin{align*}
ab = 0 & \Rightarrow a + ab = a  & \text{(zero is identity of $+$)}\\
& \Rightarrow a (1+b) = a & \text{(distributive law)}\\
& \Rightarrow 1+b = 1 & \text{(uniqueness of $1$ in the product)} \\
& \Rightarrow b=0 & \text{(identity of $+$)}
\end{align*}

Similarly you can conclude that $a = 0$, wich prove our proposition.

The first and the second result say us that $ab = 0$ if and only if $a=0$ or $b=0$ for any integers $a$ and $b$.

**Last result. Your problem.**

Let $a$ and $b$ integers such that $ab = a$. Then
\begin{align*}
ab - a = 0 \Rightarrow a (b-1) = 0
\end{align*}

Because our previous results, $a=0$ or $b-1 = 0$, wich implies that $a=0$ or $b=1$.